# Check if html <head> contain specific <link>

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to check if the html head contains this line:

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
```

I was able to find the link element using **$('head').find('link');** but I got suck on verifying which one correspond to mine since there're a lot of other links on it.

Is there a way to search the  for the whole string, something like (I know the code won't work, it's just an example):

```
$('head').find('<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">')
```

Or any other alternatives I'm open to it.

Sorry if this is a lame question, but since I'm on early stages, it's not that lame to me ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [attribute equals selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) for selecting element based on attribute value.

```
var link = $('head').find('link[href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons"][rel="stylesheet"]')
if(link.length){
   // do the rest
}
```

---

Or if you would like to compare with the string which contains the element then using [`filter()`](https://api.jquery.com/filter) method(*not tested*) do something like.

```
var link = $('head').find('link').filter(function(){
   return this.outerHTML.trim() == '<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">';
}) 
if(link.length){
   // do the rest
}
```

Comment: So simple, so easy, so nice! Thanks for the quick reply :) How can I tie that to an IF condition? IF head contains **'link[href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons"][rel="stylesheet"]'** then do THIS, if not, do THAT

Comment: @SoMeGoD just check its `length` property

Comment: @SoMeGoD : glad to help :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following code to iterate over the results of the `find()` command and see if the desired URL was found:

```
var desiredURL = "https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons";
$('head').find('link').each(function () {
if($(this).attr('href')== desiredURL)
  console.log("Found it");
});
```

Or you can just use a selector like this:

```
if($('head').find('link[href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons"][rel="stylesheet"]').length != 0)
  console.log('Found it!');
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it really helped :D